# Maya LT Batch mode

Tags: maya, mel

I'm trying to run a MEL script from the command line (OS X) using Maya LT 2015. Instructions on how to do this can be found here:

[Autodesk Maya LT - Start Maya from the command line](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-2E5D1D43-DC3D-4CB2-9A35-757598220F22-htm.html)

But when I try `Maya -prompt` or `Maya -batch -script "test.mel"` is just get this:

```
Flags:
-v                       prints the product version and cut number
-proj [dir]              look for files in the specified project dir
-file [file]             opens the specified file (use complete file name)
-archive [file]          displays a list of files required to archive the specified scene
-noAutoloadPlugins       do not auto-load any plug-ins.
-help                    prints this message
```

Seems like it doesn't support the -batch flag. Any ideas?

Comment: Maya comes with a mayabatch on Windows so there is probably one on Mac it's located in the same folder as the executable usually

Answer (score 0):

After lots of testing I came to the conclusion that Maya LT doesn't support batch mode. The documentation on Autodesk's website is incorrect (it's a copy of the regular Maya documentation).